"The breakpoint will not currently be hit" in Release mode
Debugger works perfectly fine in Debug mode, but once I change it to Release mode, it does not hit any breakpoints.

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document".

When I run it in Release mode, the only piece of information I get from the console is:

"Android application is running (debug is disabled in android project properties)."

So the main question is: How to turn it on?
I'm using:
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.11.0 Preview 5.0
Xamarin.Android SDK   13.2.2.0 (d17-5/45b0e14)

PDB files are physically present in bin/obj, in Release folders
Enabled Developer Instrumentation
Disabled AOT
Debug symbols set to: PDB file, portable across platforms
Deleted my app from emulator, to ensure the emulator uses the newest version (https://i.sstatic.net/DdlO77J4.jpg)
Mono process is attached during Debug, but is missing(and I can't find it) in Release
Added

<AndroidLinkMode>None</AndroidLinkMode> 

to my maui csproj

Reloaded projects, rebuilt solution, closed vs, deleted obj/bin, restarted computer - with no effect.


Did you mean you want the breakpoint can be hit in the release mode? And is your project type of maui or Xamarin.Android?

Debugger works perfectly fine in Debug mode, but once I change it to Realese mode, it does not hit any breakpoints That is exactly how it should behave!

@LiyunZhang-MSFT It's a MAUI project. I want to have breakpoints in Release mode, because program behaves differently in compare to Debug mode. And I think it would be much easier to figure out what's wrong with a debugger

@FreakyAli If it's impossible to have breakpoints in Release then how can I inspects strange program behaviour? Log everything into a console? I've never deployed any app, so any useful hints are going to be appreaciated

f it's impossible to have breakpoints in Release then how can I inspects strange program behaviour? Log everything into a console? Pretty much!
You can use CrashAnalytics of some sort and log exceptions
